# Autologin on debian without deskstop environment

Tags: debian, terminal, username

I want to autologin to a specific account upon booting Debian, I do not want a desktop environment for my use case and simply need to bypass the input for the username. The input method I will be using has no way of typing in letters.

Debian 12

Comment: Sorry, my answer did not relate to your system, so I deleted it.